# Quota cost of searching for videos and only needing the ID?

Tags: youtube-api

What is the quota cost of searching videos and only needing the ID returned?  I tried using the quota calculator but it doesn't output anything (and I'm assuming that the cost isn't actually 0 when you only specify "part" to be id only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Search:list` has a quota cost of 101 when `id` is specified for `part`. It's 102 for `snippet`. You can see this by going into the developer console and then running a single request with `part` set to `id` and check the quota count for the day.

To access the quota count go to the developer console, select your project, select APIs & Auth and then APIs. Select the YouTube Data API and then select Usage (or Quotas).